# If onlys and buts were candys and nuts, then everyday would be Erntedankfest

Tags: sentence-meaning

What is the meaning of the following sentence said by Dwight Schrute on a television show called the office?

> if onlys and buts were candys and nuts, then everyday would be
>   Erntedankfest.

All I know is that the word erntedankfest means "harvest festival" in English and I think "if onlys and buts" is used in another old saying referring to Christmas time. However I don't know  the origin either. Could you explain the original one and the one said by Dwight character.

Comment: More info about the original one https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/47182/origin-of-the-idiom-if-ifs-and-buts-were-candy-and-nuts

Comment: If _ifs_ and _ands_ were pots and pans, there'd be no need for tinkers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's an interesting quotation with quite a lot of cultural background. First, take a look at the link highlighted by RubioRic's comment. There, you'll find reference to several similar and earlier sayings, including “If ifs and ands were pots and pans, there’d be no work for tinkers’ hands” and "If wishes were horses, then beggars would ride".

Both of these are saying that expressions of regret like "if only..." are useless - you have to take action to improve your situation. As such, it is the sort of phrase used as a proverb to tell a child to stop moping and get on with putting things right. The Scottish/Australian singer Eric Bogle quotes another example used by his mother: "If wishes were fishes, we'd all cast nets in the sea". The saying you refer to in the question "If ifs and buts were fruits and nuts, we'd have a Merry Christmas" encapsulates the same meaning too.

In the context of The Office, there is a slightly different flavour to the current saying - "If onlys and buts..." seems to be indicating weak objections used by people in the organisation who do not want change, or are resisting some new initiative. Their reservations may be well founded, but they are being characterised as mere resistance to something new. So, the meaning here is a general encouragement to get behind new thinking, and get into action. The use of this saying, though, suggests that the character is talking down to the others, addressing them rather like an adult talking to children, and putting the "management" view on a par with the wisdom of a parent. Those with experience of a corporate environment will easily see a satirical aspect to this view. The fact that the saying is somewhat garbled and difficult to understand, emphasises that we should not take the saying at face value, and reinforces the comic effect.